# Firebase overview dashboard for different projects

Tags: firebase

In firebase we have 5 projects and 2 to 6 apps per project. Each project has their own overview / dashboard (eg. with Analytics & Crashlytics graphs).

However, we'd like to have a single dashboard as overview for all projects (if possible, with a filter for apps for each project). Is it possible to configure this in the Firebase console somehow? If not: is it possible to extract the necessary data ourselves to create our own dashboard (and where can we extract that data)?

Answer (score 1):

You can link your firebase analytics to Google Analytics. It can be done from analytics dashboard in your firebase project. It's basically an agreement that let your firebase data accessible from Google Analytics panel! (I'm not a lawyer, if you want to make sure what's going on please check it with your lawyer!)

Then in Google Analytics, you can make custom reports.
I'm not sure if custom reports are useful for your specific need, so please check beforehand.